# Injecting Exceptions into the VMCS-PIR field

Tags: x86, virtual-machine, intel, interrupt

In x86 a VMM may use posted interrupts to signal an Interrupt to a VM [(source)](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/VT-d%20Posted%20Interrupts-final%20.pdf). The detailed description can be found in Volume 3/29.6 (Posted Interrupt Processing).

According to the documentation, the `PIR` is ored with an internal register for further processing and whatever is in there is asserted as a virtual interrupt (simplified). However, I conducted some experiments and apparently, the first 32 interrupts are not delivered to the VM.

I couldn't find any documentation that explains this behavior. However, injecting the interrupt (synchronously) through the `VM-Entry Interruption-Information Field` works without any problems.

My question is did I overlook something and is there a mask that enables or disables certain interrupts in the `PIR` or is it just not supported by hardware to asynchronously inject those 'interrupts'.

Thanks!

I used Linux as guest/host and Qemu/KVM for virtualization.

Comment: IIRC, the Posted Interrupts rely on the (V)APIC. The APIC cannot deliver the first 16 interrupt vectors (see: 10.5.2 of Intel SDM Vol. 3). Furthermore 10.8.3 states, indirectly, that interrupt vectors 16-31 should not be used. I don't think you can use the Posted Interrupt an exception a fault into a VM. You could try reading the APIC error register to see if it sheds some light.